# How do I deal with a leaking toilet cistern inlet pipe?

Tags: plumbing, leak, toilet

Recently there's been an odd, damp smell coming from one of our bathrooms. On further inspection, there seems to be a leak on this pipe where it connects to the bowl (where the little red arrow is). However, it seems that the seal is made further into the bowl than I can get to or see, so it will be necessary to move the bowl.

[image]

1. What is the name of this pipe? I don't think it's the cistern inlet pipe, but it's definitely not the soil pipe.
2. The pipe looks fine, it doesn't look cracked and there doesn't seem to be a great deal of water coming from it during a flush which makes me think it's just a seal. I guess to get in at it I'd have to disconnect the pipe from the cistern and the soil pipe from the toilet, then unscrew it from the floor and move it out?

I'm always keen to give these things a go but is this one step too far? My father said he never messed with water, electric or gas but one has to live a little, no?

If you do recommend this, what should I expect to find? Any tips?

Comment: Could you get a camera into the space behind the bowl so as to take a picture of the leaking joint? Also, [here's a similar question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15278/did-i-just-ruin-the-flange-on-our-toilet?rq=1).

Comment: Check out K. Reid's link. The leak is either the compression fitting connecting the pipe to the spud, or the spud gasket itself. No need to move the toilet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's actually leaking from the bottom seal and not just flowing down from the top seal connected to the cistern? To be sure run your dry hand around the pipe near the top seal.

In any case to replace any of those seals:

1. Turn off the inlet tap to the cistern and flush until no more water remains in the cistern.  (Have some rags ready anyway as there's bound to be a small amount of water coming out residual to the cistern.)
2. Undo the nut at the cistern end by hand and lower this end of the pipe--now you can slide it back towards the cistern to remove it from the bowl.
3. Replace any broken seals and reinstall (reverse of removal instructions).
4. Open the water to cistern inlet and flush several times to check for leaks. Make sure both the cistern and bowl are well secured as any possible movement left may cause leak during usage.

Comment: Yeah, sadly the top of the pipe near the cistern is bone dry. But I see what you mean - basically, I disconnect the pipe from the cistern and work that way, rather than attempting to disconnect the bowl from the pipe. Duh! :D