# What should I be aware of as I prepare to replace my bathroom vanity with a wall mount sink?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink

We have a super tiny master bath, and the sink, which is a [vanity type](http://bignyc.org/inventory/item/gowanus/little-white-bathroom-vanity) is pretty destroyed. I think someone used some caustic cleanser on it or something. I'm thinking of replacing it with a [wall mount sink](http://bignyc.org/inventory/item/gowanus/wall-mounted-white-sink) and wondering whether I should be alert to any caveats as I embark on that project. My plan is to add a skirt to the new sink so I'm not super worried about exposing the plumbing.

I already [replaced a spud inlet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15278/did-i-just-ruin-the-flange-on-our-toilet) with the help of this forum so while I have no idea what I'm doing I'm reasonably confident that I'll work it out. Any tips?

Comment: are you sure the sink pictured is really a wall mount (I see what it says)? usually they have a much more substantial back edge. This looks like a top mount.

Comment: So I bought a sink (not the one linked above, but comparable). I think I should start a separate question about how to go about installing it, yes?

Comment: Start with the installation instructions. If you still have a specific question, write again with more info about both the sink and the wall.

Comment: No instructions! So ... new thread: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16111/how-do-i-install-this-wall-mount-bathroom-sink

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three things you need to consider:

1. Support;
2. *Support*; and
3. **Support**!

You NEED to find solid framing, probably uprights studs. You need serious screws/lag bolts into those studs. The sink is sure to come with mounting instructions as to exactly how to attach, but framing is a key.  Masonry hanging *may* be possible, but you will need very deep, serious anchors.

Many wall mount sinks can also get some extra support in the form of slender metal legs that help lift up front lip. A pedestal sink is also very compact and adds a center support. Finally there are corner sinks that rely on support from two walls.

Obviously there are a few other things, once you have solved that.  Where do the supply lines come from? Where does the drain enter the wall/floor? You might avoid the skirt (if you want) if you can position the lines to make them appear symetrical, attractive, etc? What type of fittings do you think are acceptable to see (solid chrome or brass? braided flex? etc.).  If you are certain they will be hidden, less of an issue.

Oh, by the way, if you don't have good ***SUPPORT***, the pipes will eventually leak.

Comment: +Vote....Support....Support... Support   Horizontal framing between studs to be sure of secure bolt backers is a must.

Comment: I agree with shirlock homes; but that happens mostly at the construction phase. If you can open the wall and add a horizintal support between the support studs, that is great. Does mean drywalling, etc. over the opening, though.