# How do I install this wall mount bathroom sink?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, installation, sink, mounting

I'm replacing a sink that was on a vanity cabinet and hoping to do as little busting through the perfectly good tile as possible. I heard a [rumor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16078/what-should-i-be-aware-of-as-i-prepare-to-replace-my-bathroom-vanity-with-a-wall) that I need to make very sure that the sink is adequately supported.  I'm more than happy to add legs. I bought this Glacier Bay sink second hand so I've got no manufacturer's nothing. Also, I've never done this before.

[image: Top View]
[image: View from Below]
[image: Rear View]

If I can't find studs am I basically screwed? Can I build my own legs if I'm reasonably skilled? How would I go about that?

Comment: in the last picture, what is the spacing between those holes?

Comment: also, any markings to show brand?

Comment: the bolts and washer you want are the same as found here (sorry just the first image on a web page i found) http://www.sanliv.com/wall-mount-basin-fixing-bolts-set and they will hold the weight of the sink no worries as long as they are into a solid frame not plaster

Comment: @UNECS - Using that setup would be fine if you are lagging into wood as you suggest, but those plastic anchors are NOT adequate to hold a sink into a drywall or plaster wall and should be discarded.

Comment: @bib yes that is correct like I said do not try and just fix into plaster. The plastic plugs are for fixin into bricks or concrete

Comment: @bib Glacier Bay -- I updated the question to reflect the manufacturer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the legs issue, you could fashion your own out of wood or pipe, but they need to be adjusted after the sink is hung to provide just a bit of lift. Difficult to get exact. Consider inexpensive premade legs such as [these](http://www.signaturehardware.com/product3949?origin=product-search&cvsfa=589&cvsfe=2&cvsfhu=313534353731&adtype=pla&gclid=CKb-gouG07ECFYFo4Aods1MApw):

[image: sink legs]

SUPPLEMENT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:
The legs do not go in the holes.  You want a thin buffer, maybe plastic or rubber just under and aroung the holes, then a large washer (bigger than the holes) under that, then the head of the legs, which should adjust by being rotated up to abut the washer and rubber.  If the legs seem to slip a little on the washer, try a bit of rubber/plastic between leg top and washer as well. The idea is to spread the contact area over more of the porcelain around the hole.

Comment: How do the legs connect to the sink? Do they slide through those holes and rest on the surface above? Or does something stop them from sliding all the way in?

Comment: FWIW, they came with instructions and it was super clear.

Answer (score 6):

looks like it needs bolts with very large rubber washers/gromets. even then i'd be afraid that the weight of the sink would just crack the mounting holes. the mounting holes you've got are 300mm apart, exactly as stud distance. use a stud finder.
i have a hanging sink but it came with hardware: two vertical metal straps that you attach to the studs, the metal straps lean out a bit at the top and the sink hooks onto those.

Answer (score 3):

If the studs don't line up with the mounting holes you'll have to open the wall and install blocking between the studs.You might not have to open the entire wall just a section big enough to install the blocking. I would use a 2x6 double thick. Using a combo wood/machine screw will make bolting the sink to the wall easier. This hardware has a lagbolt thread on one side that goes into the blocking. The other end has a standard machine thread. Just hang the sink on the exposed threads and install the washers and nuts.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to open the wall and add horizontal backing between the studs. Two pieces of 2x6s stacked and mounted flush with the inside edge of the drywall should be adequate.

Use two lag bolts complete with rubber washers through the two holes shown on the last picture. In addition, you'll want to also install a wall bracket similar to this:
[image]

Mount the bracket to the wall, screwing into the backing. The two tabs that stick out will allow carry the weight of the sink (the two leg bolts through the sink prevent the sink from tipping).

You can find these brackets at most plumbing suppliers or online. They come in different sizes so make sure that you get one that will fit.

Answer (score 1):

Wound up waiting for my dad to visit (he asked how long I'd had the sink -- I didn't realize it has been sitting here for over a year).

He found studs and used lead anchors and it is quite stable, though he wants us to get legs because we're expecting to have small children staying with us and they have a tendency to climb things. So we'll add legs for extra security.