# No bracket included for wall-mounted bathroom sink

Tags: sink

[image]Dealer does not have a wall-mount bracket with this sink.  I'm told to just use lag bolts.  I don't believe them.  This thing is heavy!  Is there a bracket I can find.  Is it an almost universal thing?

[image]

Comment: Can you post more details about the sink? What mfgr, make/model? Can you post a picture of it?

Comment: It is from Signature Hardware and they have assured me that I don't need a bracket.  Maybe one won't fit, but I would feel more comfortable with one.  It also looks like I might have to drill the lag bolt holes bigger or crack the porcelain.  Yikes!

Comment: Is it meant to go on a stand, and then only bolted to the wall to keep it from wobbling? those two holes look like 1/4 in or smaller, and definitely won't hold it up.

Comment: Signature Hardware's [generic instructions](http://www.signaturehardware.com/media/pdf/Wall-Mount-Sink-Installation.pdf) mention both with-bracket and without-bracket installation and say to call their customer service number with any questions.

Comment: I _really_ don't see how two bolts on the bottom corner of the sink are going to hold it on the wall when someone leans on the front of the sink.  Really seems like its made for a pedestal or stand.

Comment: I also thought it looks like its meant for a pedestal, but it seems to be a http://www.signaturehardware.com/bathroom/bathroom-sinks/carlton-wall-mount-sink-white-1.html which is shown wall-mounted wth no bracket mentioned. I'd definitely use some big fat washers as suggested by Iggy in his answer.

Comment: [This](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16111/how-do-i-install-this-wall-mount-bathroom-sink) is the kind of sink you mount with bolts. DO NOT drill porcelain fixtures. Those holes on yours are only there as a left over part of the casting process (assuming they don't go all the way through). I would mount this on top of a cabinet or a pedestal, or I would not mount it, as I see no means to hang it off a standard wall mount bracket. A picture of the front underside might shed some light.

Comment: Do those three cup-shape reliefs seem like they'd catch any of the types of brackets that Iggy outlaid? Is there a lip at the top of them?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's designed to use a standard "old school" adjustable lavatory mounting bracket:

[image]

I would fasten it at the lower holes as well.

Comment: I can't imagine hanging this just from the two bolt holes.  Use a sink mounting bracket or put it on a pedestal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping they didn't just mean lag bolts only. You'd want to at least put as big & thick as a washer that will fit in there under the lag bolts...spray painted to match of course. This spreads the load on the china, the more meat the better.

Get the Lags into the structure's framing or you may have to add a 2x10 piece of lumber as your backsplash that spans the framing. Otherwise, you'd take out the wall & put the 2x10 in the wall to then attach the sink.

It doesn't look like your sink would accommodate anything but washers, but here's what's in the Home Improvement Stores, if you notice any matching slots, indentations or other screw holes at the back or the underside. These might be able to supplement the lag support as well.

[image: Sink Brackets]

Comment: Thanks y'all.  I'll look for some fender washers, but I still can't help but wonder..and I don't know how flush it will be.  That fourth hanging plate might do the trick.

Comment: You might be right, that central area in picture 1 could be thin enough to receive it beautifully. I think any of the hangers should be used & don't drill those holes, if it falls they'll blame you for causing a fracture line. Double or triple up on the fender washers. Also, consider a pedestal for it, those small holes are typical of a pedestal setup. Which, I think you're right to be concerned with, but if the manufacturer is saying it'll support itself perfectly, then keep that receipt handy & fill out the registration card.